# Specifying settings for Options

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do you explicitly state the valid settings for an option? Take this example for instance

```
Options[myFunc] = {opt1 -> "SomeString"};
myFunc[OptionsPattern[]] := Print[OptionValue[opt1]];
```

`myFunc` prints the value of the option. If we evaluate `myFunc[opt1 -> {1, 2}]` then it prints `{1, 2}`. This function will essentially print anything that you set to `opt1`. My question is, how can I make sure that my function only accept a given number of values for `opt1`. We can start with something simple like a `String` and an `Integer`.

To have a better idea of the behavior that we would expect when given the wrong values for `opt1` we can take a look at what happens when we give the wrong values for `PlotRange` in the function `Plot`.

[image]

In the example given in the picture I purposely gave wrong values to the `PlotRange` options and gave me a message specifying the correct type of values for that particular options. It seems that it `PlotRange` ended up taking its default value and thus it return the `Graphics` object.

In the simple example what we would like to obtain is something like:

```
myFunc::sometag : Value of option opt1 -> `1` is not a string or integer.
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A straightforward solution

Here is a simple way:

```
In[304]:= ClearAll[myFunc];
Options[myFunc] = {opt1 -> "SomeString"};
myFunc::badopt = "Value of option opt1 -> `1` is not a string or integer.";
myFunc[OptionsPattern[]] :=
   With[{val = OptionValue[opt1]},
      With[{error = ! MatchQ[val, _String | _Integer]},
         If[error, Message[myFunc::badopt , val]];
         (Print[val] /; ! error)]];
```

For example:

```
In[308]:= myFunc[opt1 -> 1]

During evaluation of In[308]:= 1

In[309]:= myFunc[opt1 -> {1, 2}]

During evaluation of In[309]:= myFunc::badopt: 
Value of option opt1 -> {1,2} is not a string or integer.

Out[309]= myFunc[opt1 -> {1, 2}]
```

### Making it general with custom assignment operators

We can use the fact that `OptionValue` inside a function works with a single argument being an option name, to factor out the error-checking tedium. This is possible by using mma meta-programming facilities. Here is the code for a custom assignment operator:

```
ClearAll[def, OptionSpecs];
SetAttributes[def, HoldAll];
def[f_[args___] :> body_,OptionSpecs[optionSpecs : {(_ ->  {_, Fail :> _}) ..}]] :=
  f[args] :=
    Module[{error = False},
      Scan[
        With[{optptrn = First[# /. optionSpecs], optval = OptionValue[#]},
          If[! MatchQ[optval, optptrn ],
             error = True;
             Return[(Fail /. Last[# /. optionSpecs])[optval]]]] &, 
        optionSpecs[[All, 1]]
      ];
      body /; ! error];
```

What it does is to take a function definition as a rule `f_[args___]:>body_`, and also 
the specifications for the acceptable options settings and actions to perform upon detection of an error in one of the passed options. We then inject the error-testing code (`Scan`) before the body gets executed. As soon as the first option with inappropriate setting is found, error flag is set to `True`, and whatever code is specified in the `Fail:>code_` part of specifications for that option. The option specification pattern `(_ ->  {_, Fail :> _})` should read `(optname_ ->  {optpattern_, Fail :> onerror_})`, where `optname` is an option name, `optpattern` is a pattern that the option value must match, and `onerror` is arbitrary code to execute if error is detected. Note that we use `RuleDelayed` in `Fail:>onerror_`, to prevent premature evaluation of that code. Note b.t.w. that the `OptionSpecs` wrapper was added solely for readability - it is a completely idle symbol with no rules attached to it.

Here is an example of a function defined with this custom assignment operator:

```
ClearAll[myFunc1];
Options[myFunc1] = {opt1 -> "SomeString", opt2 -> 0};
myFunc1::badopt1 = "Value of option opt1 -> `1` is not a string or integer.";
myFunc1::badopt2 =  "Value of option opt2 -> `1` is not an integer.";
def[myFunc1[OptionsPattern[]] :> 
       Print[{OptionValue[opt1], OptionValue[opt2]}],
    OptionSpecs[{
       opt1 -> {_Integer | _String, 
           Fail :> ((Message[myFunc1::badopt1, #]; Return[$Failed]) &)},
       opt2 -> {_Integer,
           Fail :> ((Message[myFunc1::badopt2, #]; Return[$Failed]) &)}}
]];
```

Here are examples of use:

```
In[473]:= myFunc1[]
During evaluation of In[473]:= {SomeString,0}

In[474]:= myFunc1[opt2-> 10]
During evaluation of In[474]:= {SomeString,10}

In[475]:= myFunc1[opt2-> 10,opt1-> "other"]
During evaluation of In[475]:= {other,10}

In[476]:= myFunc1[opt2-> 1/2]
During evaluation of In[476]:= myFunc1::badopt2: 
Value of option opt2 -> 1/2 is not an integer.

Out[476]= $Failed

In[477]:= myFunc1[opt2-> 15,opt1->1/2]
During evaluation of In[477]:= myFunc1::badopt1: 
Value of option opt1 -> 1/2 is not a string or integer.

Out[477]= $Failed
```

### Adding option checks to already defined functions automatically

You might also be interested in a package I wrote to test the passed options: `CheckOptions`, available [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/additional_resources.html). The package comes with a notebook illustrating its use. It parses the definitions of your function and creates additional definitions to check the options. The current downside (apart from generation of new definitions which may not always be appropriate) is that it only covers older way to define options through `OptionQ` predicate (I did not yet update it to cover `OptionValue - OptionsPattern`. I will reproduce here a part of the accompanying notebook to illustrate how it works:

Consider a model function:

```
In[276]:= ClearAll[f];
f[x_, opts___?OptionQ]:= x^2;
f[x_, y_, opts___?OptionQ] := x + y;
f[x_, y_, z_] := x*y*z;
```

Suppose we want to return an error message when an option `FontSize` is passed to our function:

```
In[280]:= 
f::badopt="Inappropriate option";
test[f,heldopts_Hold,heldArgs_Hold]:=(FontSize/.Flatten[List@@heldopts])=!=FontSize;
rhsF[f,__]:=(Message[f::badopt];$Failed);
```

We  add the option - checking definitions:

```
In[283]:= AddOptionsCheck[f,test,rhsF]
Out[283]= {HoldPattern[f[x_,opts___?OptionQ]/;test[f,Hold[opts],Hold[x,opts]]]:>
                rhsF[f,Hold[opts],Hold[x,opts]],
           HoldPattern[f[x_,y_,opts___?OptionQ]/;test[f,Hold[opts],Hold[x,y,opts]]]:>
                rhsF[f,Hold[opts],Hold[x,y,opts]],
           HoldPattern[f[x_,opts___?OptionQ]]:>x^2,
           HoldPattern[f[x_,y_,opts___?OptionQ]]:>x+y,
           HoldPattern[f[x_,y_,z_]]:>x y z}
```

As you can see, once we call `AddOptionsCheck`, it generates new definitions. It takes the function name, the testing function, and the function to execute on failure. The testing function accepts the main function name, options passed to it (wrapped in `Hold`), and non-options arguments passed to it (also wrapped in `Hold`). From the generated definitions you can see what is does.

We now check on various inputs:

```
In[284]:= f[3]
Out[284]= 9

In[285]:= f[3,FontWeight->Bold]
Out[285]= 9

In[286]:= f[3,FontWeight->Bold,FontSize->5]
During evaluation of In[286]:= f::badopt: Inappropriate option
Out[286]= $Failed

In[289]:= f[a,b]
Out[289]= a+b

In[290]:= f[a,b,FontWeight->Bold]
Out[290]= a+b

In[291]:= f[a,b,FontWeight->Bold,FontSize->5]
During evaluation of In[291]:= f::badopt: Inappropriate option
Out[291]= $Failed

In[292]:= OptionIsChecked[f,test]
Out[292]= True
```

Please note that the test function can test for *arbitrary* condition involving function name, passed arguments and passed options. There is another package of mine, `PackageOptionChecks`, available at the same page, which has a simpler syntax to test specifically r.h.s. of options, and can also be applied to entire package. A practical example of its use is yet another package, `PackageSymbolsDependencies`, whose functions' options are "protected" by `PackageOptionChecks`. Also, `PackageOptionChecks` may be applied to functions in `Global'` context as well, it is not necessary to have a package.

One other limitation of the current implementation is that we can not return the function unevaluated. Please see a more detailed discussion in the notebook accompanying the package. If there is enough interest in this, I will consider updating the package to remove some of the limitations I mentioned.

Comment: nice package. Is it really true that mma does not have anything built-in to do this?

Comment: @acl Not as far as I know (which doesn't mean there isn't such a built-in mechanism, but at least it is not well documented). OTOH, built-in functions clearly use some mechanism to check that. Whether or not that mechanism is factored out from the specifics of each particular function, I don't know. As I mentioned elsewhere, bugs resulting from passing inappropriate option settings were some of the worst I ever encountered, and the struggle with them was the motivation for me to write those two packages.